# Fresco Android lib: Not able to set hotspot on "overlayImage" drawable set in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, fresco

I have set `app:overlayImage` drawable on `SimpleDraweeView` in `xml layout` for adding selector ripple effect on top of `SimpleDraweeView`. Setting `overlayImage` attribute correctly showing ripple effect on image but hot spot is always showing from center. To solve this I need the `overlayImage drawable` that I set in xml resource but I didn't find any method to get overlayImage drawable set to `SimpleDraweeView` resource programmatically.

If I prepare `GenericDraweeHierarchy` programmatically then I can prepare overlayImage drawable and can set touch listener hot spot to it. Code snippet:

```
SimpleDraweeView image = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.image);
GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder = new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(mContext.getResources());
Drawable overlayImage = getDrawable(R.drawable.image_selector);
builder.setOverlay(overlayImage);

image.setHierarchy(builder.build());

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (overlayImage != null) {
            overlayImage.setHotspot(event.getX(), event.getY());
        }
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

But I do not want to create `GenericDraweeHierarchy` programmatically as I had already set different attributes in xml and do not want to change it and set programmatically. Please suggest any method to get `overlayImage` drawable that I had set in `xml layout` resource.

What I tried but did not work:

1. Used `getTopLevelDrawable()` and `getDrawable()` method of
   `SimpleDraweeView` for getting `drawable` and `setHotSpot` to it.
2. Used `getTopLevelDrawable` method of `SimpleDraweeView` after image
       loaded by setting ControllerListener to it and setting hotSpot to
       obtained drawable.

Please let me know if I can add hot spot in any other way.

Comment: Let me know if more details needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried hard to add ripple overlay over `Fresco SimpleDraweeView`.
I didn't find the exact solution for making ripple effect works properly on `SimpleDraweeView`, but I have come up with two approaches for adding working ripple effect:

1. Wrap `SimpleDraweeView` inside `FrameLayout` and set
   `android:foreground` property to `FrameLayout`. Add
   `android:clickable` property to `FrameLayout` or add click listener
   to it. Code snippet:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/image_container"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height"wrap_content"
       android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_selector"
       android:clickable="true">

       <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
           android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="20dp"
           android:layout_height="20dp"/>

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

   Set clicklistener for `FrameLayout` container:

   ```
   findViewById(R.id.id/image_container).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClicklistener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // Do your stuff
           }
       })
   ```
2. Extend `SimpleDraweeView` and draw ripple `drawable` on top of it.
   Following solution was provided by "boxcounter" on github. Check
   following [link](https://gist.github.com/boxcounter/89fe6c3de997ac6dd473) for Custom `SimpleDraweeView` that shows ripple
   effect on top of `SimpleDraweeView`.

I have reported same issue on [Fresco library issue page](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/912). Hope it will get answered soon.

**Fresco #912 issue update:**

Few days back I provided a commit to Fresco which fix this issue. Now in `com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.11.0` we just need to set ripple drawable as value for `app:overlayImage` attribute and it will work perfectly.